# Passing variables into package.json

Tags: javascript, reactjs, docker, npm

I'm working on React app. I need to pass a variable into package.json from .env file:

`{"proxy": "ENV_VAR"}`

Is it possible to do that?

Also, we build app using docker. Could we rewrite that key using docker anyhow?

Answer (score 2):

What is the end goal ? 
Is it to define a process direction on build ?
If it is then you dont need to pass it to package.json but to read it in the build script.
For example start the build task like this ( its doesn't in package.json or not )

```
PROXY=SOME_PROXY npm run-script build
```

If its something like create-react-app did you check : this https://create-react-app.dev/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development/

So you can read the env

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(
    '/api',
    proxy({
      target: process.env.ENV_VAR,
      changeOrigin: true,
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: can I use it like 'PROXY=SOME_PROXY npm start' ?

Comment: Yes setting it before the command defines it a temporary variable for the script to be executed.
For example DEBUG=* node app.js ( for expressjs application ) enables the verbose output for debugging.